# How to add image to High-chart?

Tags: highcharts, legend

I have plot in high-chart with 1000 polygon series but i cannot show all legends. So i just want to keep four legend(after grouping multiple polygon series) and want to write their legends.

```
1. case 1.   Red color box
2. case 2.   Blue color box 
3. case 3.   Green color box
4. case 4.   white color box
```

But how can i put that legend in highchart as high chart only generate legend based on series data. Or can i add static image already generated seperately in highchart multi-polygon series (showinlegend: flase) so that it should appear as legend in polygon series?

Comment: Use a [linkedTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.linkedTo) between series, then print only 4 of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your requirement , if you just want to show four non-clickable legend like indicators you can use renderer like below :

```
function(chart) {
    chart.renderer.rect(80, 75, 10, 10).attr({
    fill: '#C5FFC5',

}).add(); chart.renderer.text("Series 1" ,100, 85).add();
      chart.renderer.rect(80, 95, 10, 10).attr({
    fill: 'red' 
}).add();
    chart.renderer.text("Series 2" ,100, 105).add();
      chart.renderer.rect(80, 115, 10, 10).attr({
    fill: 'green' 

}).add();
chart.renderer.text("Series 3" ,100, 125).add(); 
}
```

**Edit** in your code ,place this code like below:

```
    $.getJSON('data10.json', function(data) {
    options.series=data;
    options.chart.zoomType='x'; 
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        chart.renderer.rect(80, 75, 10, 10).attr({
            fill: '#C5FFC5',
            stroke: 'black',
                'stroke-width': 1
        }).add();
        chart.renderer.text("Series 1", 100, 85).add();
        chart.renderer.rect(80, 95, 10, 10).attr({
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
                'stroke-width': 1
        }).add();
        chart.renderer.text("Series 2", 100, 105).add();
        chart.renderer.rect(80, 115, 10, 10).attr({
            fill: 'green',
            stroke: 'black',
                'stroke-width': 1
        }).add();
        chart.renderer.text("Series 3", 100, 125).add();



});
```

[See the working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/onhfLqdm/24/)

Comment: I tried to run by adding the following code in my code but i have not got any legend as output. https://jsfiddle.net/ex3L066z/1/

Comment: you placed function at wrong place , also your chart is not drawn as you missed data10 and data20.json files,

Comment: in your function , call it after chart declaration like the update in answer above below (set the coordinate  x,y whatever position you want)